# Gremlin - simultaneously limit traverse iterations and search for edge property

Tags: gremlin, janusgraph, gremlin-server, gremlinpython

I have a (broken) piece of gremlin code to generate the shortest path from a given vertex to one which has the parameter `test_parameter`. If that parameter is not found on an edge, no paths should be returned.

```
s.V(377524408).repeat(bothE().has('date', between(1554076800, 1556668800)).otherV()) /* date filter on edges */
    .until(or(__.bothE().has('test_property', gt(0)),
           loops().is(4)))                                /* broken logic! */
    .path()                                             
    .local(unfold().filter(__.has('entity_id')).fold())   /* remove edges from output paths*/
```

The line that's broken is `.until(or(__.outE().has('test_property', gt(0)), loops().is(4)))`.

At present - and it makes sense as to why -  it gives all paths that are 4 hops from the starting vertex.

**I'm trying to adapt it so that if the traverse is at 4 iterations, and if the property `test_property` is *not* found, then it should not return any paths. If `test_property` is found, it should return only the path(s) to that vertex.**

I've attempted to put a `times(4)` constraint in and removing the `loops()` condition, but don't know how to have both the `times(4)` this and the `.has('test_property', gt(0))` constraint.

Comment: You only require the `test_property` to be on any out-edge that's incident to the final vertex? Not on every traversed edge?

Comment: Correct. I want to get the shortest path to `test_property` (which may or may not exist on any edge), but only if `test_property` exists within x=4 iterations (otherwise do not return any paths since none exist)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Daniel's answer has few issues (see comments).
This query returns the correct result:

```
g.V(377524408)
  .repeat(bothE().has('date', between(1554076800, 1556668800)).otherV().simplePath().as("v"))
  .until(and(bothE().has('tp', gt(0)), loops().is(lte(4))))
  .select(all, "v")
  .limit(1)
```

The `simplePath()` is required so we won't go back and forth and avoid circles.

The repeat loop is until the condition is met AND we have not reached max hop.

The `limit(1)` return only the first (shortest) path. Omit to get all paths.

Note that if the graph is directed it is better to use `outE()` and not `bothE()`.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
s.V(377524408).
  repeat(bothE().has('date', between(1554076800, 1556668800)).otherV().as('v')).
    times(4).
  filter(bothE().has('test_property', gt(0))).
  select(all, 'v')
```

Also note, that I replaced your `local(unfold().filter(__.has('entity_id')).fold())` with something much simpler (assuming that the sole purpose was the removal of edges from the path).

Comment: Thanks kindly Daniel, when I get the chance I'll test this and get back to you

Comment: This answer is not correct. It will bounce back and forth, and return only paths of length 4.